Integral using spherical harmonics
I am a bit struggling to calculate a quantity involving spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)$. We parameterize a surface in spherical coordinates as:
\begin{equation}
\xi(\theta,\varphi) = R \sum_{l,m} a_{lm}Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)
\end{equation}
Where $Y_{lm}(\theta,\varphi)$, are the spherical harmonics.
The excess energy is defined as an intergal over the sphere of radius R:
\begin{equation}
\Phi= \frac{\gamma_0 R^2}{2} \int_\Omega |\nabla \xi(\theta,\varphi)|^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta d\varphi
\end{equation}
I need to show that:
\begin{equation}
\Phi= \frac{\gamma_0 R^2}{2} \sum_{l,m} |a_{lm}|^2 (l-1)(l+2)
\end{equation}
I suspected using green's identity to get $\Delta Y_{lm}$ to use the definition of spherical harmonics.
Reference paper : https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3013638
Formula used in paper.
Thank you very much.

Cross-posted to Physics Stack Exchange.
